# Codeigniter If else statement condition

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to include if else statement in my codeigniter. When user search a place, it can view the information of the place from database. And I'm trying to add in if else statement. If the reviews are more then 5 users rate that place as "Noisy", then the system will automatically rate it as "The place is Noisy". (The noise review is input by the user using radio button when writing the review and save it into database). Below is the code that I working on.

//view.php

```
<style>
#searchbutton{
position: absolute;
left:300px;
top:30px;
}
fieldset {
background-color:#EFEAEA;
margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
 padding: 20px;
border-radius: 1px;
width:900px;
margin-left:220px;
margin-top:-10px;
}
#user{
font-style:italic;
font-size: 12px;
text-align:right;
}
#titlereview {
font-style: italic;
font-size:20px;
}
#review {
font-size:16px;
}
</style>

<?=form_open_multipart('viewreview/view');?>

<?php $search = array('name'=>'search',);?>
<?php $noise = array('name'=>'noise',);?>

<div id = "searchbutton">
<?=form_input($search);?><input type=submit value="Search" /></p>
</div>
<?=form_close();?>

<div class = "tablestyle">

<fieldset>
<?php foreach ($query as $row): ?>

<div id = "user">User: <?php echo $row->name; ?><br>
Visited time: <?php echo $row->visitedtime; ?><br>
</div>

 <div id = "titlereview">"<?php echo $row->titlereview; ?>"<br></div>

 <div id = "noise"><?php echo $row->noise; ?><br></div>

 <div id = "review"><?php echo $row->yourreview; ?><br><hr><br></div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</fieldset>

<!--$noise is the field form database!-->
<?php if ($noise='yes'>5){
echo 'The place is Noisy';
}
else {
echo 'The place is Not Noisy';
}
?>
</div>
```

//controller

```
<?php
class viewreview extends CI_Controller {

public function view($page = 'viewreview') //writereview page folder name
{
    $this->load->model('viewreview_model');
    $data['query'] = $this->viewreview_model->get_data();
    $this->load->vars($data);
    if ( ! file_exists('application/views/viewreview/'.$page.'.php')) //link
    {
        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = 'View Review'; 
    //$data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter
    $this->load->helper('html');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('viewreview/'.$page, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
 }
}
?>
```

//model

```
<?php
class viewreview_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}
public function get_data()
{
    $match = $this->input->post('search');
    $this->db->like('sitename',$match);
    $this->db->or_like('titlereview',$match);
    $this->db->or_like('yourreview',$match);
    $this->db->or_like('suggestion',$match);

    $query = $this->db->get('review');      //pass data to query
    return $query->result();

  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Just a note I have noticed your controllers and models do not have first letter upper case on class and file name if your using CI3 it is recommended. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model and http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your question correct:

Model:

```
public function number_of_noise_report() {
      $this->db->select('id'); // Change it to what column name you have for id
      $this->db->from('table');
      $this->db->where('noise', 'Yes') // 'Yes' or 'yes', depending on what you have in db
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->num_rows();
}
```

And I would include it in Controller:

```
// Code before
$data['query'] = $this->viewreview_model->get_data();
$data['noise_stat'] = $this->viewreview_model->number_of_noise_report(); // ** UPDATED
// Code after
```

And then in view:

```
if($noise_stat > 5){
    echo '<div id = "noise">Noisy<br></div>';
} else {
    echo '<div id = "noise">Do Something Here<br></div>';
}

// OR SIMPLY
<div id = "noise">
<?php if($noise_stat > 5){ echo 'Noisy<br>';
} else { echo 'Somrthing<br>'; } ?>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. But if the user rate the noise of place by using "yes" or "no". How can I add in?

Comment: Please check UPDATE in Controller and let us all know how it works.

Comment: It not work. It will only echo "Noisy" even change the condition.  For "$something" what should I put actually? I am not quite understand on that part.

Comment: okay, may be you remove "Something" from controller.. And just right the term "Yes" or "yes" (depending on the way you have in db) in model.. UPDATED IN MY ANSWER TOO.. take a look..

Comment: Thank you so much. It help me lot. I know how it work now. But come another problems. It count my whole database instead of particular place that user search.

Comment: Ahh, got it.. check my update for Model.. And it should work now. And if all good, dont forget to accept the answer :-)